# How to normalize sign of coefficients in standard form linear equation

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a representation of a linear equation in standard form ($ax + by + c = 0$) which I am representing as a set of coefficients: $a, b, c$.

I want to normalize these so that any two equations that represent the same line can be compared programatically to see if they're equal just using the co-efficients. For this I need the co-efficients of any two equations representing the same line to be equivalent after normalizing.

I normalized the values by dividing all coefficients by $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}$ which scales the coefficients to be the same but I don't know how to account for sign changes in this.

For example, if I have equations:
$2x + -4y + 2 = 0$ (represented as 2, -4, 2) and $-2 x+ 4y + -2 = 0$ (represented as -2, 4, -2), how can I transform the coefficients to make them equal?

Answer (score 1):

This is the same problem as standardizing projective homogeneous coordinates. You have the right first step, namely, dividing all coordinates by the magnitude. Now you have the problem that a set of coordinates and its negative are equivalent. If the last non zero coordinate is negative, then negate all the coordinates. This gives standardized coordinates.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean "last non negative coordinate is negative?" Either a or b, and/or c can be zero as well as negative which is why I'm struggling with this.

Comment: @AnavGagneja Oops! I meant non zero coordinate. Fixed now.